# How to replace last href occurrence in a string?

Tags: javascript, regex, regexp-replace

The text is something like the following

```
<a href="http://example.com/test this now">Stuff</a>

More stuff

<a href="http://example.com/more?stuff goes here">more</a>

last thing

<a href="http://example.com/more?lasthing goes here">more</a>
```

I need to replace what's inside the last `href` ocurrence in the text, with another reference as `http://realreference.com/real?the one to replace`

I can actually change the `href` of all ocurrences in the string with the global flag `g` after the regex `/href="(.*?)"/` and a function like the following:

```
string.replace(/href="(.*?)"/g, () => {
return `href="http://realreference.com/real?the one to replace"`;
})
```

I would need to only change it in the last `href` ocurrence of the string, which in this case it's `href="http://example.com/more?lasthing goes here"`

Comment: You should rather not be doing this using Regex in the first place, but with a DOM parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for a pure regex solution, you can use the following to find the last match:

```
pattern(?![\s\S]*pattern)
```

Example: `href="(.+?)"(?![\s\S]*href="(.+?)")`

See it yourself: [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/blFaul/1)

Answer (score 0):

Find all `href` with [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) and replace only last

Answer (score 0):

You can use [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) in order to query the desired element in the DOM. Using [:last-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type) will make it select the last element of the type you select. Therefore, with this code in the first line, you will get the last `<a>`. After you get the element, you can replace its `href` attribute by using [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute).

```js
let last_a = document.querySelector('a:last-of-type');
last_a.setAttribute('href', 'http://realreference.com/real?the one to replace');
console.log(last_a);
```

```html
<a href="http://example.com/test this now">Stuff</a>
More stuff
<a href="http://example.com/more?stuff goes here">more</a>
last thing
<a href="http://example.com/more?lasthing goes here">more</a>
```